# How can I Insert multiple rows with one query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I made a code allowing me to **GET** data from an API and **insert** it into a **database**.
But I encounter a problem my api contains about 20 million data and to insert everything in my database it will take me 43 days :)

I think the problem comes from the fact that I insert the data one by one.

That's why I'm looking for how to execute all my queries at once.

The problem is that I get my data as a list[dict] like that :

```
<class 'list'>
{
    'siren': 'siren_int',
    'nic': 'nic int',
    'dateCreationEtablissement': '2000-09-26',
    'uniteLegale': {'denominationUniteLegale': None, 'nomUniteLegale': 'last name', 'prenomUsuelUniteLegale': 'firstname'},
    'adresseEtablissement': {
        'numeroVoieEtablissement': None,
        'libelleVoieEtablissement': 'street name',
        'codePostalEtablissement': 'postal code',
        'libelleCommuneEtablissement': 'commune name',
    }
}
```

Currently my code looks like this :

```
    def insertGlobalBdd(self, rows : list[dict]) :
        cursor = self.bdd.cursor() 
        for element in rows:
            rows.append((element["siren"], self.TestFormat(element["uniteLegale"]["nomUniteLegale"]), 
                        self.TestFormat(element["uniteLegale"]["prenomUsuelUniteLegale"]), self.TestFormat(element["uniteLegale"]["denominationUniteLegale"]), 
                        element["dateCreationEtablissement"]))

        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s.dbo.Entreprise (siren, nomUniteLegale, prenomUsuelUniteLegale, denominationuniteLegale, dateCreationEtablissement) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""".format(",".join(str(i) for i in rows)))
        self.bdd.commit()
```

would you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: insert into %s.dbo.enterprise values (value1, value2, ...), (value1, value2, ...), (value1, value2, ...)

Comment: I don't understand why in your code you append in the array rows that you are currently looping on ?

Comment: Side note, `INSERT INTO %s` isn't going to work; you cannot parametrise a database name. Unless you are injecting your values, and then you have a much more **dangerous** problem on your hands and you **need** the address that ASAP.

Comment: @Toothgip If I understood the question correctly, the loop is in theory present because my list[dict] has several lines. But I don't know how to do it

Comment: @Larnu I know my code is not secure at all but no one will have access to it ^^

Comment: That isn't an excuse, @Jerry . Do you leave your front door unlocked when you go out because you know no one else is going to be coming down your road? Don't leave your application's "front door" open; code properly to start with. Then you don't end up with awfully well known and avoidable security vulnerabilities in production code, because that awful habit has been stamped out of you.

Comment: I agree with you @Larnu :) but for the moment my code is only a test and my problem is mainly to know how I can execute several requests at the same time

Comment: If you want to pass multiple rows, you could use a table type parameter, which (you guessed it), requires you to parametrise your statement. Alternative (less efficient) methods are to pass a XML or JSON parameter, and then consume that into a dataset in the SQL (which, again, requires parametrisation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with 'executemany'.

example

```
    task_all[
           (1,  "Jahanzabe", 30),
           (2,  "Steve", 20),
           (3,  "Haider", 30),
           (....All Others...)]
    cur.executemany('Insert in to Table_name(id, name, no) 
     values(?,?,?)', task_all)
    con.commit()
```